# regex conditional matching

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to use `re.findall` to find this pattern:

```
01-234-5678
regex:
(\b\d{2}(?P<separator>[-:\s]?)\d{2}(?P=separator)\d{3}(?P=separator)\d{3}(?:(?P=separator)\d{4})?,?\.?\b)
```

however, some cases have shortened to 01-234-5 instead of 01-234-0005 when the last four digits are 3 zeros followed by a non-zero digit.

Since there does't seem to be any uniformity in formatting I had to account for a few different separator characters or possibly none at all. Luckily, I have only noticed this shortening when some separator has been used...

Is it possible to use a regex conditional to check if a separator does exist (not an empty string), then also check for the shortened variation?

So, something like `if separator != '': re.findall(r'(\b\d{2}(?P<separator>[-:\s]?)\d{3}(?P=separator)(\d{4}|\d{1})\.?\b)', text)`

Or is my only option to include all the possibly incorrect 6 digit patterns then check for a separator with python?

Comment: Why not allow a varying number of digits (e.g. `\d{1,4}`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe The named capture groups was a suggestion from SO when I asked how to enforce the same separator is used throughout the regex so I wouldn't capture something like 01234:5678.

Comment: Yep; just figured that out, sorry!

Comment: @jonrsharpe this has been a tricky affair trying to deal with parcel numbers from different sources with no apparent formatting enforced. Maybe just running a second findall with `[\s-:/]\d{1}` (without the `?` after the separator)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the last group of digits to be *"either one or four digits"*, try:

```
>>> import re
>>> example = "This has one pattern that you're expecting, 01-234-5678, and another that maybe you aren't: 23:456:7"
>>> pattern = re.compile(r'\b(\d{2}(?P<sep>[-:\s]?)\d{3}(?P=sep)\d(?:\d{3})?)\b')
>>> pattern.findall(example)
[('01-234-5678', '-'), ('23:456:7', ':')]
```

The last part of the pattern, `\d(?:\d{3})?)`, means one digit, optionally followed by three more (i.e. one or four). Note that you don't need to include the optional full stop or comma, they're already covered by `\b`.

---

Given that you *don't* want to capture the case where there is no separator and the last section is a single digit, you could deal with that case separately:

```
r'\b(\d{9}|\d{2}(?P<sep>[-:\s])\d{3}(?P=sep)\d(?:\d{3})?)\b'
#    ^ exactly nine digits
#         ^ or
#                             ^ sep not optional
```

See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/jF9nH1/1).

Comment: The pattern seems to return the same results the original pattern does, incorrectly returning 6 digit strings such as: `(u'007209', u'')` when 6 digit strings should only be returned if the <separator> is not an empty string.

Comment: @Verbal_Kint maybe make *"no separator"* a separate case, (i.e. `(\d{9}|...)(?P<sep>[-:\s])...`)?

Comment: so an additional regex pattern and additional findall? That seems the easiest... or possibly justvuse what I have and use python to throw away any elements with len = 6...

Comment: I see, very simple. This works well, thanks for the link. I've never seen this site before even after all my google searches. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear why you are using word boundaries, but I have not seen your data.

Otherwise you can shorten the entire this to this:

`re.compile(r'\d{2}(?P<separator>[-:\s]?)\d{3}(?P=separator)\d{1,4}')`

Note that \d{1,4} matched a string with 1, 2, 3 or 4 digits

If there is no separator, e.g. "012340008" will match the regex above as you are using `[-:\s]?` which matches 0 or 1 times.

HTH

Comment: the use of boundaries is probably incorrect. I am trying to prevent the pattern from matching a 9 digit pattern within a larger number of digits, like: 012345678911, which might return: 012345678

Comment: @Verbal_Kint no, that seems like a reasonable use of the boundaries.

Comment: This pattern also returns 6 digit strings with empty string separator, where I only want 6 digits if the separator is not an empty string (rather separator = `:` or `/` or `-` or `\s`)